# Google maps javascript API getting 403 (OK)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google maps javascript API and everyone once in a while the map tiles don't load and I see this in the console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)

I see it for both the tiles as well as for the static image library.

If anyone has any idea what is causing this or what this means that'd be helpful, thank you

Comment: What are the URLs? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a static map? If you are there is another API that you need, [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro)

Comment: See also [What are the usage limits for the Google Maps APIs?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) "The Google Maps JavaScript API, Google Static Maps API, and Google Street View Image API have a default daily limit of 25,000 map loads per day. If your site or application generates 25,000 map loads or more each day, for more than 90 consecutive days, we’ll attempt to get in touch with you to talk about payment. Don’t worry, if you go over the limits, we won't immediately shut off your API access or display error messages on your site." It nay also cause such error